# Laravel Livewire not mounting value from datepicker

Tags: laravel, datepicker, laravel-livewire, flowbite, laravel-livewire-wiremodel

I am using Flowbite Datepick plugin with my Livewire and Livewire Component is not mounting value of the datepicker and is NULL upon selecting date

```
                <div class="relative max-w-sm">
                    <label class="form-label mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white" for="date_filed">{{ trans('cruds.leaveApplication.fields.date_filed') }}</label>
                    <div class="absolute py-2.5 left-0 flex items-center pl-3 pointer-events-none">
                      <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6 2a1 1 0 00-1 1v1H4a2 2 0 00-2 2v10a2 2 0 002 2h12a2 2 0 002-2V6a2 2 0 00-2-2h-1V3a1 1 0 10-2 0v1H7V3a1 1 0 00-1-1zm0 5a1 1 0 000 2h8a1 1 0 100-2H6z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
                    </div>
                    <input datepicker datepicker-autohide type="text" wire:model="leaveApplication.date_filed" id="date_filed" name="date_filed" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full pl-10 p-2.5  dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="Select date">
                    <div class="validation-message">
                        {{ $errors->first('leaveApplication.date_filed') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem in this way.

```
<div class="relative max-w-sm">
    <div class="relative max-w-sm">
        <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3 pointer-events-none">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"
                fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                    d="M6 2a1 1 0 00-1 1v1H4a2 2 0 00-2 2v10a2 2 0 002 2h12a2 2 0 002-2V6a2 2 0 00-2-2h-1V3a1 1 0 10-2 0v1H7V3a1 1 0 00-1-1zm0 5a1 1 0 000 2h8a1 1 0 100-2H6z"
                    clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <input datepicker datepicker-buttons datepicker-autohide type="text" id="date"
            datepicker-format="yyyy-mm-dd"
            class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full pl-10 p-2.5  dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
            placeholder="Select date">
    </div>
    <script>
        const datepickerEl = document.getElementById('date');

        datepickerEl.addEventListener('changeDate', (event) => {
            window.livewire.emit('dateSelected', event.detail.date);
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

*In the script I emit of function `updateDate` of Livewire using `listeners` which are Livewire own*

This is a example

```
protected $listeners = ['dateSelected' => 'updateDate'];

public function updateDate($date)
{
    $this->date = $date;
}
```

In this shape I get the value of the input of datepicker

Answer (score 1):

For thirty party javascript, livewire sometimes works not well. In this case, you can add a script like below:

```
<script>
    $('#date_filed').change(function(e) {
        @this.set('leaveApplication.date_filed', $(this).val())
    })
</script>
```

And you can use wire:ignore to instructs Livewire to not update the element datepicker input:

```
 <div wire:ignore>
     <input datepicker datepicker-autohide type="text" wire:model="leaveApplication.date_filed" id="date_filed" name="date_filed" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full pl-10 p-2.5  dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="Select date">
 </div>
```